# Hadoop MapReduce sort reduce output using the key

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, comparator

down below there is a map-reduce program counting words of several text files.
My aim is to have the result in a descending order regarding the amount of appearences.

Unfortunately the program sorts the output lexicographically by the key. I want a natural order of the integer value.

So I added a custom comparator with `job.setSortComparatorClass(IntComparator.class)`. But this doesn't work as expected. I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:404)
Caused by: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:498)
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:355)
    at WordCount$IntComparator.compare(WordCount.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.compare(MapTask.java:987)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.QuickSort.sortInternal(QuickSort.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1277)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

I've listed the whole program below as there may be a reason for the exception which I obviously don't know. As you can see I am using the new mapreduce api (`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*`).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

/**
 * Counts the words in several text files.
 */
public class WordCount {
  /**
   * Maps lines of text to (word, amount) pairs.
   */
  public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private Text word = new Text();
    private IntWritable amount = new IntWritable(1);

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String textLine = value.toString();

      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(textLine);
      while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
        word.set((String) tokenizer.nextElement());

        context.write(word, amount);
      }
    }

  }

  /**
   * Reduces (word, amount) pairs to (amount, word) list.
   */
  public static class Reduce extends
      Reducer<Text, IntWritable, IntWritable, Text> {

    private IntWritable amount = new IntWritable();
    private int sum;

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> valueList,
        Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      sum = 0;

      for (IntWritable value : valueList) {
        sum += value.get();
      }

      amount.set(sum);
      context.write(amount, key);
    }
  }

  public static class IntComparator extends WritableComparator {
    public IntComparator() {
      super(IntWritable.class);
    }

    private Integer int1;
    private Integer int2;

    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] raw1, int offset1, int length1, byte[] raw2,
        int offset2, int length2) {
      int1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(raw1, offset1, length1).getInt();
      int2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(raw2, offset2, length2).getInt();

      return int2.compareTo(int1);
    }

  }

  /**
   * Job configuration.
   * 
   * @param args
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws ClassNotFoundException
   * @throws InterruptedException
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
      ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
    Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
    Job job = new Job(configuration);
    job.setJobName("WordCount");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setSortComparatorClass(IntComparator.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPath);

    FileSystem.get(configuration).delete(outputPath, true);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain what the `natural order of the integer value` of a string is? Currently you are trying to compare the first 4 bytes from a string (wtf?).

Comment: Not the string, the IntWritable, which is the key.

Comment: But your key is text, there is no int to be sorted anywhere.

Comment: The output of the reducer uses IntWritable as the key type.
See `context.write(amount, key);` with amount being an IntWritable.

Comment: Sorting doesn't happen after the reducer.

Comment: do you want to sort output of Reducer?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut:
But it seems like (without the sorter set explicitly) the output is sorted lexicographically by the key.

Comment: @twid:
Yes, I want to sort it by the amount of occurences descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparator step occurs between the `Mapper` and `Reducer`, which wont work for you as you swap the key and value around in the `Reducer` itself.

The default `WritableComparator` would normally handle your numerical ordering if the key was `IntWritable`, except it's getting a `Text` key thus resulting in lexicographical ordering.

As to why exactly the output at the end isn't sorted by your written out `IntWritable` key, I'm unsure. Perhaps it has something to do with the way `TextOutputFormat` works? You might have to dig deeper into `TextOutputFormat` source code for clues on that, but in short, setting the sort comparator probably won't help you here I'm afraid.

Comment: That means actually it should sort using the compare function of IntWritable?

Answer (score 1):

As [quetzalcoatl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565247/quetzalcoatl) said Your comparator is not useful, Since it is used between Map and reduce phase and not after Reduce phase. So to accomplish this you need to either sort in `cleanup` of `Reducer` or write another program to sort output of reducer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need sort by value. There are 2 ways to achieve this. But in short you need 2 map-reduce, i.e. run one more map reduce on the output of first Map reduce.

After completing normal map-reduce do one more map reduce where you take output of first map reduce as input to second map reduce. In second map reduce's map phase you can use a custom class as key e.g. 
    `class WordCountVo implements WritableComparable<WordCountVo>` 
and you must override 
    `public int compareTo(WordCountVo wodCountVo)`
 method. 
In WordCountVO you can keep both word and count but compare based on count only. E.g. below are the member variables for WordCountVO

```
private String word;
private Long count;
```

Now when you receive key-value pairs in second reducer then your data will be all sorted by values. All you need to do is to write the key value pairs using context! Hope this helps.