# Hadoop sorting issue (Alternate title: 1175 is not less than 119!)

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop and done with a typical "count the IP addresses in a log" exercise. Now I'm trying to sort the output by running a second MapReduce job immediately after the first. Almost everything is working, except for the fact that the output collector isn't quite processing the sort the way I'd like. Here's a snippet of my output:

```
-101   71.59.196.132
-115   59.103.11.163
-1175  59.93.51.231
-119   127.0.0.1
-1193  115.186.128.19
-1242  59.93.64.161
-146   192.35.79.70
```

I can't figure out why, for example, 1175 is considered a lower value than 119. I've tried playing around with Comparators, but it hasn't had any positive effect.

The Map and Reduce jobs for the data collection are both standard and non-problematic. They output a list much like the snippet above, but completely unsorted. The SortMap, SortReduce, and Runner classes are a little different. Here's my Runner class:

```
public class Runner {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(Runner.class);
    JobConf sortStage = new JobConf(Runner.class);

    conf.setJobName("ip-count");
    conf.setMapperClass(IpMapper.class);
    conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);       
    conf.setReducerClass(IpReducer.class);
    conf.setOutputValueGroupingComparator(IntWritable.Comparator.class);


    //Input and output from command line...
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    sortStage.setJobName("sort-stage");
    sortStage.setMapperClass(SortMapper.class);
    sortStage.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    sortStage.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    sortStage.setReducerClass(SortReducer.class);
    sortStage.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    sortStage.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    //Input and output from command line...
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(sortStage, new Path(args[2]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(sortStage, new Path(args[3]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
    JobClient.runJob(sortStage);

}
}
```

The "SortMapper":

```
public class SortMapper extends MapReduceBase 
  implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
private static final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);  
public void map(LongWritable fileOffset, Text lineContents,
  OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
  throws IOException {
  {
    //Grab the whole string, formatted as (Count /t IP), e.g., 101  128.10.3.40
    String ip = lineContents.toString();
    //Output it with a count of 1
    output.collect(new Text(ip), one);
  }
}
}
```

The "SortReducer":

```
public class SortReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable,      
IntWritable, Text> 
{
public void reduce(Text ip, Iterator<IntWritable> counts,
  OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
  throws IOException{

  String delimiter = "[\t]";
  String[] splitString = ip.toString().split(delimiter);

  //Count represented as 0-count to easily sort in descending order vs. ascending
  int sortCount = 0-Integer.parseInt(splitString[0]);
  output.collect(new IntWritable(sortCount), new Text(splitString[1]));
  }
}
```

This is just a single-node job, so I don't think partitioning is a factor. Sorry if this is a trivial matter - I've spent an embarrassing amount of time on the problem and couldn't find anything that dealt with this particular sorting issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "I can't figure out why, for example, 1175 is considered a lower value than 119" you _do_ know that the string "1175" is alphabetically less than the string "119" and you are sorting strings, not integers, right?  Are you asking how to make them integers?

Comment: Yikes, I guess I must be! I tried to output the count as an IntWritable, which I thought was treated as an int. Are IntWritables treated as strings?

Comment: I believe the answer to that is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134341/hadoop-mapreduce-sort-reduce-output-using-the-key).

Answer (score 1):

Your numbers are being compared 'alphabetically'. This is because there are strings. If you imagine alphabetical sorting, aabc comes before aac. If you turn these into numbers, 1123 comes before 113.

If you want numeric comparison, you are going to have to convert them to integers.

Comment: As far as I can tell, my outputs should be IntWritable, right? I tried changing the output type to integers and the result was the same. I have no idea why they're coming out as strings :\